# Parse tree and grammar information

Tags: grammar, parsing, concrete-syntax-tree

Does anyone know where to find good online resources with examples of how to make grammars and parse trees? Preferably introductory materials.
Info that is n00b friendly, haven't found anything good with Google myself.

**Edit:** I'm thinking about theory, not a specific parser software.

Comment: You'll get much more precise answers, with pointers to software toolkits, if you specify the programming language you're using. :-)

Comment: I'm know a bit java and trying to learn ML. But I was more interested in the theory of generating parsetrees than specific parsetools.

Comment: The theory behind grammars, parsing, and compiler technology in general is by nature not newbie-friendly.  You may find it difficult to find material on the topic simply because there's a lot of necessary knowledge to fully understand the theory.

Answer (score 4):

Not online, but maybe you should take a look at [Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811) by Aho et al. This is  a standard text that has been evolving for 30 years (if you count the 1st [Dragon Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201000229), published in 1977

Comment: The Dragon Book is a great book very difficult for a n00b.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's where I learned it...

http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/class/sp08/cs273/

Click on the lectures tag, scroll through till you find the lectures on the material you are talking about.

Love my alma mater.  God bless them, they never take down their lectures in any class and you can go and read any of them anytime you want.

edit: Looks like you want lecture11

Answer (score 1):

Antlr?

http://www.antlr.org/

Has a quite good IDE for designing a grammar, and a lot of generators for different languages.

Answer (score 0):

[www.goldparser.com](http://www.goldparser.com)

The tools are free and good to work on. It has technical and theoretical tutorials, lots of info, tools and code generators for many langs.

Answer (score 0):

in C,C++ use [lex and bison](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/)
in java use [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)
this is a beautiful antlr video [tutorial](http://vimeo.com/groups/29150/videos/8377605)